# How do I supply a source file to the visual studio debugger later?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a WPF project in Visual Studio 2015 and hit an exception in a NuGet package. It asked me for the source file and I foolishly cancelled the file browser dialog thinking I could work it out. Turns out I couldn't and downloaded the source, but I now can't figure out how to pass the debugger the files it wanted and it's not asking any more. Has anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I supply a source file to the visual studio debugger later?

In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the `Solution` -> `Properties` -> `Common Properties` -> `Debug Source Files`.

There are two options here:

**Directories containing source code:** and **Do not look for these source files:**

[image]

You can try to remove (all) entries from the second list (Do not look for these source files), then Visual Studio should ask you for the source path again.

If it not work, you can add the path of source files to the first list(Directories containing source code).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! clearing the list worked beautifully.